# Homogeneous second-order differential equation with constant Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

> **Problem** Prove that if the Wronskian of any two solutions of differential equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ is constant, then $p(x)$ is zero.

*My attempt.* : Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be two solutions of given differential equation. Note that the Wronskian $W=W[y_1,y_2]$ satisfies $W'+p(x)W=0$. Since $W$ is constant, we get $p(x)W=0$.

*Question.* How do I show that $W$ cannot be equal to zero? If there are two solutions $y_1$, $y_2$ that are linearly independent, then $W[y_1,y_2]\neq 0$. But I am not certain of the existence of such solutions.

---

My question is : If a second-order ODE has a solution, do there exist two solutions that are linearly independent?

Comment: The wronskian can be $0$, just set $y_1=y_2$ and $p$ not constant to find a counterexample to the statement. You need to require that the solutions are linearly independent.

Comment: @GitGud I know it. My question is 'it is possible that W is not zero?'

Comment: The wronskian isn't zero if, and only if, the two two solutions are linearly independent. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @gitgud No. There is no second-order ODE that every two solutions of given ODE is linearly dependent?

Comment: `There is no second-order ODE that every two solutions of given ODE is linearly dependent` This statement is false. Just take any non trivial solution and the trivial solution which are linearly dependent. I really don't see what you want to ask, as far as I can tell I've answered your question. Maybe you're not asking what you want to ask.

Comment: @GitGud I modify my question what I meant to ask was. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The answer yes. This is in the books. Answering this question requires one to know what one can use. In fact if it is an equation of degree $n$, there are $n$ linearly independent solutions.

Comment: @GitGud It is true even if $q$ is not continuous?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use [Abel's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity) to show that if the Wronskian of any two solutions of the differential equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y = 0$ (on an interval $I$) is constant, then $p(x) = 0$. (If $\int_{x_0}^{x} p(t) dt$ is constant $\forall$ $x \in I$, then $p(t) = 0 $)

The answer to your last question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217096/why-do-we-need-two-linearly-independent-solutions-for-2nd-order-linear-ode).

Answer (score 1):

We know that if $W(x)$ be the Wronskian of the differential equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$, then $$W(x)=Ae^{\int p(x) dx}\qquad \text{where $A$ is constant.}$$

Now if $W(x)=constant = c$(say), then $$Ae^{\int p(x) dx}=c$$
$$\implies e^{\int p(x) dx}=d$$
$$\implies {\int p(x) dx}= \log d=k \text{(say)$\qquad$ where $k$ is constant}$$
Differentiating both side with respect to $x$ $$p(x)=0$$

---

${}$

If a second-order ODE has a solution, then there exist two solutions that are linearly independent. In fact, in general, an $n^{th}$-order ODE has $n$ linearly independent solutions.

For more details about this you may find the following link

[An nth-order ODE has n linearly independent solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089286/an-nth-order-ode-has-n-linearly-independent-solutions)